# Multiple grep separator and display file information

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep, find

I want to grep multiple information in files with multiple separator, and display file informations, with only one command.

```
./WBL-FILE-S-1-execution79065.html
./WBL-FILE-S-1-execution79066.html
./WBL-FILE-S-1-execution79067.html
```

If I do :

```
find . -type f -name « *WBL-FILE* » | xargs grep "Fichier&nbsp;lu"
```

I have results like :

```
./WBL-FILE-S-1-execution79065.html:<td title="Message">Fichier&nbsp;lu&nbsp;/opt/data/in/bl/000334_iwel1C010116730.blc.TRT</td>
./WBL-FILE-S-1-execution79065.html:<td title="Message">Fichier&nbsp;lu&nbsp;/opt/data/in/bl/000312_iwel1C010116727.blc.TRT</td>
./WBL-FILE-S-1-execution74707.html:<td title="Message">Fichier&nbsp;lu&nbsp;/opt/data/in/bl/000420_iwel1C010116284.blc.TRT</td>
```

The goal is to get the date of file, filename, the XXXXXX_iwel number, and the CXXXXXXXXX number.

Example :

```
2021-07-13 13:47 WBL-FILE-S-1-execution79065.html 000334 010116730
2021-07-13 14:48 WBL-FILE-S-1-execution79065.html 000312 010116727
2021-07-14 14:49 WBL-FILE-S-1-execution74707.html 000420 010116284
```

I almost succeed to extract the different part, but after that, I can't get the "ls" (date) information on the original file.

Is there a way to do that only with one line combinaison of commands ?

Thank you

Comment: The notion of "one command" has little value in Bash, since you can just pipe pretty much everything to achieve your goals. In your command for example there are 2 commands involved: `find` and `xargs` (one may also say `grep` is another command)

Comment: `« *WBL-FILE* »` is not valid syntax; did you mean `"*WBL-FILE*"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add the file's date, `grep` alone won't cut it anymore. Also, extracting **XXXXXX**_iwel and C**XXXXXXXXX** and printing these numbers *on the same line* is not possible with `grep` alone.

Therefore I would switch to `perl`:

```
perl -nle 'use POSIX "strftime";
BEGIN { sub mtime { strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime((stat $ARGV)[9]) } }
/Fichier&nbsp;lu.*?(\d+)_iwel.*?C(\d+)/ && print join " ", mtime, $ARGV, $1, $2'
```

Sine all your files are in the same directory, you can use

```
perl ... *WBL-FILE*
```

For a recursive file search, use `find -exec` instead of `find | xargs`. This is not only more efficient, but also safer in case some filenames contain whitespace or special symbols like `"'\`.

```
find -type f -name '*WBL-FILE*' -exec perl ... {} +
```

Comment: Thx a lot, I thought there was a simplier way to do but it's logic in a certain way :)

Answer (score 2):

For each file, you can display the information you need with one `awk` command.

```sh
awk 'match($0, /Fichier&nbsp;lu.*[^0-9]([0-9]*)_iwel[^C]*C([0-9]*)/, array) { date_command="date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\" --date @$(stat -c %Y " FILENAME ")"; date_command | getline formatted_date; close(date_command); print formatted_date, FILENAME, array[1], array[2]}' /path/to/file
```

It can be rewritten like this for clarity:

```sh
awk 'match($0, /Fichier&nbsp;lu.*[^0-9]([0-9]*)_iwel[^C]*C([0-9]*)/, array) {
  date_command="date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\" --date @$(stat -c %Y " FILENAME ")";
  date_command | getline formatted_date;
  close(date_command);
  print formatted_date, FILENAME, array[1], array[2]
}'
```

Basically it does 3 things:

- It matches all lines including `Fichier&nbsp;lu` and captures the numbers of `XXXXXX_iwel` and `CXXXXXXXXX` into an array
- It calls a command line to get the modification date of the file with the desired format
- It prints all the information you want on the same line

You can plug it after `find` of course.

```sh
find . -name "*WBL-FILE*" | xargs awk 'match($0, /Fichier&nbsp;lu.*[^0-9]([0-9]*)_iwel[^C]*C([0-9]*)/, array) { date_command="date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\" --date @$(stat -c %Y " FILENAME ")"; date_command | getline formatted_date; close(date_command); print formatted_date, FILENAME, array[1], array[2]}'
```

Result:

```sh
2021-07-28 10:45:50 ./WBL-FILE-S-1-execution79065.html 000334 010116730
2021-07-28 10:45:50 ./WBL-FILE-S-1-execution79065.html 000312 010116727
2021-07-28 10:46:41 ./WBL-FILE-S-1-execution74707.html 000420 010116284
```

### Side notes

I used the `match` function, which is part of GNU Awk, also known as `gawk`. If you don’t have it, it’s still possible but it requires another way to capture the string.

The trickiest part is probably the command for getting the date because we need to build a string for the command and then call it and then store the result in a variable. It’s a bit messy. It also requires a two-step process: get the date in Epoch time (i.e. numbers of seconds from 1970-01-01) and then format this value with the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format. On the other hand you can adapt these steps very easily. For instance you can display the date with another format by changing the `+\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` string sent to [date](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date). Or you can display the creation date instead of the last modification date by changing the `-c %Y` option sent to [stat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat).

The command is not robust to filenames and folders containing whitespaces. To fix this, first you may use an ugly syntax to replace `$(stat -c %Y " FILENAME ")"` with `$(stat -c %Y '"'"'" FILENAME "'"'"')"` during the date call. Yikes. This is due to how we build the string in one line. Secondly you may use either of those commands to make sure filenames are passed correctly (to simplify, let’s say the awk script is stored in the `AWKSTRING` variable).

```sh
find . -name "*WBL-FILE*" -print0 | xargs -0 awk "$AWKSTRING"
find . -name "*WBL-FILE*" -exec awk "$AWKSTRING" {} \;
find . -name "*WBL-FILE*" -exec awk "$AWKSTRING" {} +
```

The latter is probably a bit more optimal than the others, but not all versions of `find` support it.